# How to implement standard formatting and validation while typing expiry date (Debit/Credit cards) in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, mobile-development

I have a text field for entering a credit card expiration date in MM/YY format, which is a 4-digit string like 0523. The first two digits represent the month and the second two digits represent the year. I am using visual transformation to show a slash between the month and year.

I need a function to format the input and prevent the user from typing invalid months (e.g., 13, 44, 21) and previous years.

I have done a lot of research on this, but I haven't found a proper solution for preventing users from typing invalid dates.

Can anyone help me implement this in Jetpack Compose?

[image: This is the ui part]

Answer (score 0):

This solution will not prevent user from entering invalid characters but will validate the input. Then, based on if the input is valid or not, you can decide whether to proceed further or not.
The regex used here will only allow months from 01 to 12 and current year or any year in future.

```kotlin
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var isError by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val currentYear = java.time.Year.now().value.toString().substring(2)
val regexPattern = """^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/$currentYear|[2-9]\d$""".toRegex()
OutlinedTextField(
  value = text,
  onValueChange = {
    text = it
    isError = !regexPattern.matches(it)
  },
  isError = isError,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Locale


const val EXPIRATION_DATE_MONTH_PREFIX = 1
const val EXPIRATION_DATE_MONTH = 2
const val EXPIRATION_DATE_YEAR_PREFIX = 3
const val EXPIRATION_DATE_YEAR = 4
const val DATE_FORMAT_yyMM = "yyMM"
const val DATE_FORMAT_MMyy = "MMyy"


fun validateAndFormatExpirationDateEntry(expirationDate: String): String {
    if (expirationDate.length == EXPIRATION_DATE_MONTH_PREFIX) {
        val enteredMonth = expirationDate.toInt()
        return if (enteredMonth in 2..9) "0$enteredMonth"
        else "$enteredMonth"
    }
    if (expirationDate.length == EXPIRATION_DATE_MONTH) {
        var enteredMonth = expirationDate.toInt()
        enteredMonth = if (enteredMonth > 12) 1 else enteredMonth
        return if (expirationDate == "00") "0"
        else if (expirationDate[0] == '0') "0$enteredMonth"
        else "$enteredMonth"
    }
    if (expirationDate.length == EXPIRATION_DATE_YEAR_PREFIX) {
        val currentYearPrefix = (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) % 100) / 10
        if (expirationDate[2].toString().toInt() < currentYearPrefix)
            return expirationDate.substring(0, 2)
    }
    if (expirationDate.length == EXPIRATION_DATE_YEAR) {
        return try {
            val enteredMonth = expirationDate.substring(0, 2)
            val currentDate =
                SimpleDateFormat(
                    DATE_FORMAT_yyMM,
                    Locale.US
                ).format(Calendar.getInstance().time)
            val enteredDate = SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_yyMM, Locale.US).format(
                SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_MMyy, Locale.US).parse(expirationDate)
            )
            if (enteredDate >= currentDate) expirationDate
            else "$enteredMonth${expirationDate[2]}"
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            expirationDate
        }
    }
    if (expirationDate.length > EXPIRATION_DATE_YEAR) return expirationDate.substring(0, 4)
    return expirationDate
}
```